# Dynamic UL items not displaying side by side

Tags: html, css

I am attempting to create a horizontal scroll of a ul populated by an ajax call to an xml document. As constituted, the content will scroll but the list items are stacked rather than side by side. Research suggests that I can achieve the desired result with some simple css. However, I have been unable to successfully make this happen...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
    <meta name="Content-Script-Type" content="text/javascript">
    <meta name="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css">
    <link href="css/wneRSS.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<div id="rss">
    <div class="list"><ul class="feeder"></ul></div>
</div>

</body>



<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "XMLSource",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml){
    $(xml).find('row').each(function(){
      var sfirst = $(this).find('First').text();
      var slast = $(this).find('Last').text();
      var scity = $(this).find('PermanentCity').text();
      var sstate = $(this).find('PermanentRegion').text();
      $("<li></li>").html(sfirst + " " + slast + " - " + scity + ", " + sstate).appendTo("#rss ul");
    });
  },
  error: function() {
    alert("An error occurred while processing XML file.");
  }
  });
});
</script>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #373737;
    color: white;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#rss {
    width: 1920px;
    height: 82px;
    margin:0px;
}

.list ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    float: left;
    display: inline;
    width: auto;
}

.list ul li {
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    display: inline;
}





.feeder {
 font-size: 40px;
 line-height: 82px;
 -moz-transform:translateX(100%);
 -webkit-transform:translateX(100%);    
 transform:translateX(100%);
 animation: scroller 60s linear infinite;
}


@keyframes scroller {
 0%   { 
  transform: translateX(100%);      
 }
 100% { 
 transform: translateX(-100%); 
 }
}
```

Comment: You want it to animate left to right ?

Comment: no... right to left

Comment: Your sample exactly as shown shows the results floated -- not stacked as you describe.  I conclude that either the styling you have posted here is being overwritten by other styling or your container (.list) is not wide enough to contain all the floated list items in a horizontal layout.

Comment: adding auto to width of the container did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Added width=auto to the container solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your container may not be wide enough to accommodate your list items.  You need to nest the unordered list elements in a container wide enough that they do not break.